# Is there any Python3 compatible module to read/write IPTC-data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, iptc

I've already tried [IPTCInfo3](https://github.com/jamesacampbell/iptcinfo3).
But after successful installation with

```
pip3 install IPTCInfo
```

i get an import error:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct 11 2016, 04:59:56) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)] on darwin

from iptcinfo import IPTCInfo

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'iptcinfo'
```

Comment: Does [gexiv2](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2) work on Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install IPTCinfo` is what you don't want - [it's the python2 only package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IPTCInfo). What you linked to isn't on PyPI, but that doesn't mean you can't install it!

Download the zip file from github, extract it, and in the resulting folder run:
`python setup.py install`. I ran into an issue with the file naming, not sure if it was just a result of something I had done though - you can just open up `setup.py` and change `py_modules=['iptcinfo3'],` to `py_modules=['iptcinfo'],` if you get the same issue about there being no `iptcinfo3` module.

From there you should be able to import as you normally would. I just ran a command for it and it worked.

Comment: Please see my answer, iptcinfo3 exists now.

Answer (score 6):

There is a Python 3 version of iptcinfo now. It is `pip3 install iptcinfo3` and it works great out of the box with batteries included. Please try it out and submit any issues on github. I am the maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same. It appears that the [`gexiv2`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2) branch of `exiv2` mentioned by @mcepl above [supports both python 2 and 3](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gexiv2/PythonSupport).

According to the Gnome gexiv2 site,future versions of GIMP will use `gexiv2` for metadata which should ensure future support.

Answer (score -3):

Try this command :

```
pip install --upgrade python-iptables
```

It worked for me.